# How to clip the excess image in the box - CSS

Tags: css

so i did make border and on the top i have a picture of something, now the picture have a background and i want keep the background but the corners getting outside from my border are rotate by 45deg and the image rotate by -45deg and now i want make the picture fit inside the border.

```css
.image-box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px grey;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.image-box-2 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image-box-2">
    <img src="image/image2.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

how its look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/grTSl.jpg

Comment: I got it, you it should fit inside not over the border? you can check my answer below. and you can add screen shot in existing question no need to add that as answer!

Comment: this is how its look like on my script or our: https://imgur.com/2nulF9W

Comment: check my answer below and you can see the image is fit in the box with transform.

Comment: yes but the image rotating too, and i mean that rotate only the border

Comment: Ok, you need like this? https://imgur.com/2nulF9W not to rotate you mean?

Comment: yes but the image like is inside

Comment: The image must not rotate but it should be inside the box?

Comment: yes, this is how i want it

Comment: Check the code now.

Comment: i mean like this one: https://imgur.com/lJUqNwI (with photoshop)

Comment: overflow:hidden to image box

Comment: @AnonyMM check now.

Comment: @Manjuboyz YES!, { overflow: hidden; }, you fix for me it! Massive Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow:hidden;` in the main div.

```css
.image-box {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px grey;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: 50px;
  overflow: hidden; /* use this */
  margin: 50px;
}

.image-box-2 img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="image-box">
  <div class="image-box-2">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/301/301" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```